# Why does the process rate of a MapReduce task start slow and then increase?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I run a MapReduce job in Linux and recorded the process rate of tasks (number of bytes processed per second). I noticed that the process rate started slow and kept increasing until it became stable. Note that every task runs in a separate JVM. Is that slow start because of the JVM?

The figures below show the cumulative process rate of two tasks run in different machines with different speed. One machine is about 2X faster than the second one. Note that the task run in fast machine reached stability faster.

[image: Task run in fast machine]

[image: Task run in slow machine]

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: How do you know you're not just observing your cluster's task ramp up time (YARN's scheduling of tasks)?

Comment: Here, the JVM launching time is not included. I start recording the process rate after the first byte processed.

Comment: Are you looking at a single task or all the tasks cumulatively?

Comment: The figures show the cumulative process of a single task. First figure is for a task running on a fast machine, while the second figure is for a task running on a slow machine.